# Updating SQL table with PHP code from generated table

Tags: php, mysql

Could someone help me figure out why this isn't working?

My update function isn't working on my php code. I have a breaking point that lists all the information at the end of the for loops, which is correct information. However it prints it about 50 times per ID. Also, it doesn't update the SQL table.

How could I fix this?

Snippet:

```
if ( isset( $_POST[ 'RemarketingRollCall' ] ) )
                            {

echo 'RollCall called ';
foreach($_POST['userid'] as $param1){
  foreach($_POST['name'] as $param2){
    foreach($_POST['job'] as $param3){
      foreach($_POST['monday'] as $param4){
        foreach($_POST['tuesday'] as $param5){
          foreach($_POST['wednesday'] as $param6){
            foreach($_POST['thursday'] as $param7){
              foreach($_POST['friday'] as $param8){

                $idnumber = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, $param1 );
                $Name = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, $param2 );
                $Job = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, $param3 );
                $Monday = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, $param4 );
                $Tuesday = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, $param5 );
                $Wednesday = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, $param6 );
                $Thursday = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, $param7 );
                $Friday = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, $param8 );

                echo "(". $idnumber . " " . $Name . " " . $Job . " " . $Monday . " " . $Tuesday . " " . $Wednesday . " " . $Thursday . " " . $Friday . ")";
                $sql = "UPDATE `Employee` SET `Job`='$Job', `Monday`='$Monday', `Tuesday`='$Tuesday', `Wednesday`='$Wednesday', `Thursday`='$Thursday', `Friday`='$Friday' WHERE `ID`=$idnumber";
                mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                if ( !mysqli_query( $con, $sql ) )
                  {
                    die( 'Error: ' . mysqli_error( $con ) );
                  }                 
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
mysqli_close( $con );
?>
//putting a script here
```

This is the output: http://gyazo.com/3006df320d4857314ea486936f656ba3

Here is my table generation:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($remarketingRoll)) {
  echo "<form id='RemarketingRollCall' method='POST'>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td contenteditable='false' align='center' width='11%'><input style='verticle-align:center;' type='text' name='userId[]' value=". $row['userId'] ." readonly></td>";
  echo "<td contenteditable='false' align='center' width='11%'><input style='verticle-align:center;' type='text' name='name[]' value=". $row['Name'] ." readonly></td>";
  echo "<td contenteditable='false' align='center' width='11%'>
  <select name='job[]'>
  <option value='Remarketing'>Remarketing</option>
  <option value='IOS'>IOS</option>
  <option value='Computers'>Computers</option>
  </select></td>";
  if ( strcmp( $row['Monday'], 'Attended' ) == 0 ){
  echo "<td contenteditable='false' align='center' width='11%'>
  <select name='monday[]'>
  <option value='Attended''>Attended</option>
  <option value='Absent'>Absent</option>
  </select></td>";
  } else if ( strcmp( $row['Monday'], 'Absent' ) == 0 ){
  echo "<td contenteditable='false' align='center' width='11%'>
  <select name='monday[]'>
  <option value='Absent'>Absent</option>
  <option value='Attended''>Attended</option>
  </select></td>";
  } else {
  echo "<td contenteditable='false' align='center' width='11%'>
  <select name='monday[]'>
  <option> </option>
  <option value='Absent'>Absent</option>
  <option value='Attended''>Attended</option>
  </select></td>";
  }
  if ( strcmp( $row['Tuesday'], 'Attended' ) == 0 ){
  echo "<td contenteditable='false' align='center' width='11%'>
  <select name='tuesday[]'>
  <option value='Attended''>Attended</option>
  <option value='Absent'>Absent</option>
  </select></td>";
  } else if ( strcmp( $row['Tuesday'], 'Absent' ) == 0 ){
  echo "<td contenteditable='false' align='center' width='11%'>
  <select name='tuesday[]'>
  <option value='Absent'>Absent</option>
  <option value='Attended''>Attended</option>
  </select></td>";
  } else {
  echo "<td contenteditable='false' align='center' width='11%'>
  <select name='tuesday[]'>
  <option> </option>
  <option value='Absent'>Absent</option>
  <option value='Attended''>Attended</option>
  </select></td>";
  }
  if ( strcmp( $row['Wednesday'], 'Attended' ) == 0 ){
  echo "<td contenteditable='false' align='center' width='11%'>
  <select name='wednesday[]'>
  <option value='Attended''>Attended</option>
  <option value='Absent'>Absent</option>
  </select></td>";
  } else if ( strcmp( $row['Wednesday'], 'Absent' ) == 0 ){
  echo "<td contenteditable='false' align='center' width='11%'>
  <select name='wednesday[]'>
  <option value='Absent'>Absent</option>
  <option value='Attended''>Attended</option>
  </select></td>";
  } else {
  echo "<td contenteditable='false' align='center' width='11%'>
  <select name='wednesday[]'>
  <option> </option>
  <option value='Absent'>Absent</option>
  <option value='Attended''>Attended</option>
  </select></td>";
  }
  if ( strcmp( $row['Thursday'], 'Attended' ) == 0 ){
  echo "<td contenteditable='false' align='center' width='11%'>
  <select name='thursday[]'>
  <option value='Attended''>Attended</option>
  <option value='Absent'>Absent</option>
  </select></td>";
  } else if ( strcmp( $row['Thursday'], 'Absent' ) == 0 ){
  echo "<td contenteditable='false' align='center' width='11%'>
  <select name='thursday[]'>
  <option value='Absent'>Absent</option>
  <option value='Attended''>Attended</option>
  </select></td>";
  } else {
  echo "<td contenteditable='false' align='center' width='11%'>
  <select name='thursday[]'>
  <option> </option>
  <option value='Absent'>Absent</option>
  <option value='Attended''>Attended</option>
  </select></td>";
  }
  if ( strcmp( $row['Friday'], 'Attended' ) == 0 ){
  echo "<td contenteditable='false' align='center' width='11%'>
  <select name='friday[]'>
  <option value='Attended''>Attended</option>
  <option value='Absent'>Absent</option>
  </select></td>";
  } else if ( strcmp( $row['Friday'], 'Absent' ) == 0 ){
  echo "<td contenteditable='false' align='center' width='11%'>
  <select name='friday[]'>
  <option value='Absent'>Absent</option>
  <option value='Attended''>Attended</option>
  </select></td>";
  } else {
  echo "<td contenteditable='false' align='center' width='11%'>
  <select name='friday[]'>
  <option> </option>
  <option value='Absent'>Absent</option>
  <option value='Attended''>Attended</option>
  </select></td>";
  }
  echo "<td name='week[]' contenteditable='false' align='center' width='11%'>" . $row['Week'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "</form>"; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $index = 0;
 foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
   $idnumber = $_POST['userId'][$index];
   $Name = $_POST['name'][$index];
   $Job = $_POST['job'][$index];
   $Monday = $_POST['monday'][$index];
   $Tuesday = $_POST['tuesday'][$index];
   $Wednesday = $_POST['wednesday'][$index];
   $Thursday = $_POST['thursday'][$index];
   $Friday = $_POST['friday'][$index];
   $index++;
   // put your sql UPDATE here
}
```

You do not show the closing brace for the while{

```
  </select></td>";
  }
  echo "<td name='week[]' contenteditable='false' align='center' width='11%'>" . $row['Week'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "</form>";
```

If it is here:

```
  </select></td>";
  }
  echo "<td name='week[]' contenteditable='false' align='center' width='11%'>" . $row['Week'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "</form>";
}  // is it here????????????
```

If the brace is where I think it is you need to move it to here

```
  </select></td>";
  }

  echo "<td name='week[]' contenteditable='false' align='center' width='11%'>" . $row['Week'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}  // <==========================
  echo "</form>";
```

And move:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($remarketingRoll)) {
  echo "<form id='RemarketingRollCall' method='POST'>";
```

To:

```
echo "<form id='RemarketingRollCall' method='POST'>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($remarketingRoll)) {
```

### Update 2

Replace:

```
$idnumber = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, $param1 );
$Name = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, $param2 );
$Job = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, $param3 );
$Monday = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, $param4 );
$Tuesday = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, $param5 );
$Wednesday = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, $param6 );
$Thursday = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, $param7 );
$Friday = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, $param8 );
```

With:

```
$idnumber = $_POST['userId'][0];
$Name = $_POST['name'][0];
$Job = $_POST['job'][0];
$Monday = $_POST['monday'][0];
$Tuesday = $_POST['tuesday'][0];
$Wednesday = $_POST['wednesday'][0];
$Thursday = $_POST['thursday'][0];
$Friday = $_POST['friday'][0];
```

**end of update 2**

---

**Update**

Add this line of code to dump what is being submitted:

```
var_export($_POST);
```

---

Don't use foreach.

Change all the foreach:

```
$param2 = $_POST['name'];
$param3 = $_POST['job'];
$param4 = $_POST['monday'];
$param5 = $_POST['tuesday'];
$param6 = $_POST['wednesday'];
$param7 = $_POST['thursday'] ;
$param8 = $_POST['friday'];
```

To:

```
$param2 = $_POST['name'];
$param3 = $_POST['job'];
$param4 = $_POST['monday'];
$param5 = $_POST['tuesday'];
$param6 = $_POST['wednesday'];
$param7 = $_POST['thursday'] ;
$param8 = $_POST['friday'];
```

Comment: Okay. This fixed the issue with it going through dozens of times. But I still can't get the freakin' thing to update my database.

Comment: Okay. I got it to actually use the UPDATE thing, but it cleared everything.

Comment: But what about when I add more to the database? This is meant to iterate through the entire database.
-
- basically, what my goal is, I have a table generating from a database that has dropdown boxes so users can edit it. The update function is suppose to update every field.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about.  All I see here is a POST being made and the posted data being used to update a single db record.  Is the data being updated now?

Comment: Just updated my main post with my table generation so you can see where the data comes from. The page generates a table full of information from a table, and inserts everything into an array. The table it generates has dropdown boxes with possible choices for the user to select, and thats what the update code is for. The user should be able to go through the entire table for each ID that is posted, and select options under the days. The update function should update all of these at once, and not just one of them.

Comment: The closing bracket is under the last echo that is shown in the code. The bracket for some reason went out of the code box on this site.

Comment: That means for every record you are creating a separate form.  Move the `<forem>` and `</form>`  outside of the while loop.  Then dump the $_POST again.

Comment: I am however getting a PHP notice for `Undefined Offset: 1` on the `$idnumber = $_POST['userId'][$index];` - Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: It is defined here `array ( 'userId' => array ( 0 => '4', 1 => '6', ),`  The index value 1 is here: `1 => '6',`  Is the 2nd record being updated?

Comment: It looks like the 'foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){' is trying to loop more times then there are entries. I keep getting an error `Undefined Offset: 2` through `Undefined Offset: 8`.

Comment: sorry, I'm not really sure how to check you off/up vote.